# Need To filter output inrange between identifiers I.e grep between 1: this pattern and 2: that pattern and only show containing text

Tags: bash, shell

I need to filter the output of a dictionary I've managed to get the output down to the following example. I want to only output text between the Identifying pattern of 1: and 2:
I know of a solution with python but would like to accomplish this in the shell. I think it is possible with sed but not sure how.

### n 1: feline mammal usually having thick soft fur and no ability
to roar: domestic cats; wildcats [syn: {cat}, {true cat}]
2: an informal term for a youth or man; "a nice guy"; "the guy's
only doing it for some doll" [syn: {guy}, {cat}, {hombre},
{bozo}]
3: a spiteful woman gossip; "what a cat she is!"
4: the leaves of the shrub Catha edulis which are chewed like
tobacco or used to make tea; has the effect of a euphoric
stimulant; "in Yemen kat is used daily by 85% of adults"
[syn: {kat}, {khat}, {qat}, {quat}, {cat}, {Arabian tea},
{African tea}]
5: a whip with nine knotted cords; "British sailors feared the
cat" [syn: {cat-o'-nine-tails}, {cat}]
6: a large tracked vehicle that is propelled by two endless
metal belts; frequently used for moving earth in construction
and farm work [syn: {Caterpillar}, {cat}]

```
  v 1: beat with a cat-o'-nine-tails
  2: eject the contents of the stomach through the mouth; "After
     drinking too much, the students vomited"; "He purged
     continuously"; "The patient regurgitated the food we gave him
     last night" [syn: {vomit}, {vomit up}, {purge}, {cast},
     {sick}, {cat}, {be sick}, {disgorge}, {regorge}, {retch},
     {puke}, {barf}, {spew}, {spue}, {chuck}, {upchuck}, {honk},
     {regurgitate}, {throw up}] [ant: {keep down}]
```

Comment: Please prefix your code/data with four white spaces. Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your exact desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better solution since I had an extra step after `sed` by using `grep` to remove unwanted lines. I still feel like I can accomplish this with only `sed` but here is my solution thus far:

```
dict -h dict.tu-chemnitz.de cat | sed -n '/1:/,/2:/p' | grep -v 2:
```